# "Too few arguments to function" error in backpack admin CRUD

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I've configured the backpack admin with my laravel project and after integrating I face the below error whenever I want to edit or delete or preview a record, however, I can see the list and create a new record.

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DepartmentCrudController::show(), 0 passed in /Users/meysam/Documents/projects/ttm-ppm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 1 expected
```

This is my backpack routing (custom.php):

```
Route::group([
    'prefix'     => config('backpack.base.route_prefix', 'admin'),
    'middleware' => array_merge(
        (array) config('backpack.base.web_middleware', 'web'),
        (array) config('backpack.base.middleware_key', 'admin')
    ),
    'namespace'  => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin',
], function () { // custom admin routes

   Route::crud('department', 'DepartmentCrudController');

}); // this should be the absolute last line of this file
```

and this is my web.php

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Route::middleware([UserPannel::class])->group(function(){
....


});

Route::middleware([AdminPannel::class])->group(function(){

....

});
```

Update:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
class DepartmentCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;


    public function setup()
    {
        if(trim(strtoupper(Auth::user()->role)) != trim(strtoupper(config('enums.roles.manager'))))
            throw new HttpResponseException(redirect(backpack_url('dashboard')));
        CRUD::setModel(Department::class);
        CRUD::setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/department');
        CRUD::setEntityNameStrings('department', 'departments');
    }


    protected function setupListOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setFromDb(); // columns
    }

    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setValidation(DepartmentRequest::class);

        CRUD::setFromDb(); // fields


    protected function setupUpdateOperation()
    {
        $this->setupCreateOperation();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the route? Are you passing all the required aprameters?

Comment: please share DepartmentCrudController line 54

Comment: In your url you need to pass `DEPARTMENT_ID` like this: `http://yoursite/department/DEPARTMENT_ID`

Comment: @OMR I've added it

Comment: @Lessmore I call the 'departemnt/{id}/edit'

Comment: please share all DepartmentCrudController

Comment: @OMR this is all of it. if you are looking for the edit method it's on the CrudController which this class extended from it. and the CrudController is for Backpackadmin and also its edit method is like: edit($id)

Comment: did you miss "}"  before protected function setupUpdateOperation ?